# How to deploy LogMeIn Free via GPO to entire domain?

Tags: deployment, group-policy, remote-desktop

I am looking to deploy LogMeIn to several clients.  I am using [LogMeIn Central](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/central/) with LogMeIn free.

Central allows me to create an install URL to send to a client, but I want to create a GPO to deploy the LogMeIn to the entire domain of computers.

None of the local users have local Admin rights to their workstations,  which is why I want to deploy LogMeIn through AD instead of installing via the Deployment Link.

Thank you,
Keith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't at all easy to do because LogMeIn wants you to purchase their for-pay product, which has that functionality.

My business partner wrote a script to perform this installation automatically. It involves using a scripted browser control to download the one-off MSI that LogMeIn generates (with a time-dependent serial number embedded inside it) and then installing that MSI. We wrote it as a work-for-hire for a Customer, so I can't give it to you w/o their permission. It's proven to be somewhat brittle and unreliable.

I'd recommend that you either pony up for the for-pay product, write such a script yourself (for likely as much as the for-pay product will cost), or just manually install it.

Answer (score 1):

Seem's that you can generate a msi from there own website now. (Only for Logmein central users)

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy the program and have it install on the end users machine using GPO, however you can't specify the logmein account to tie it to. You can only do that manually. To do this follow these instructions

Open GPO Manager
Click Computer Configuration
Click Policies
Click Software Settings
Click Software Installation
Right Click on the open area and choose new then package.

Then go to the .msi package you downloaded from logmein. (make sure it is saved to a location on the network where everyone can access it.)

This installs the application on to the users computer remotley, but like I said you have to manually add it to your account. If you have central you can create a temp account that only allows them to add computers then give them that login info to put in after the install.